# Combining two queries into one using Group By in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

Currently, I'm trying to get all submissions from one user along with all comments on a particular submission. The way I am doing it is extremely inefficient (query inside of a loop).

I have been told to use Group By, but I'm not sure how to get it working properly.

The first query to select all submission info is:

```
SELECT
    submissions.user_id,
    submissions.id,
    submissions.quote,
    submissions.filename,
    submissions.date_added,
    submissions.views
FROM
    `submissions`
WHERE
    submissions.user_id = ?
ORDER BY
     submissions.date_added
DESC
```

The second (to get the comment count) is:

```
SELECT
    count(id) AS `comments`
FROM
    `comments`
WHERE
    submission_id = '{$subId}'
```

Those work, but since they will become slow, so I tried to come up with this, but am not sure how to execute it properly.

```
SELECT
    submissions.user_id,
    submissions.id,
    submissions.quote,
    submissions.filename,
    submissions.date_added,
    submissions.views,
    COUNT(comments.id) as `comment`
    comments.submission_id
FROM
    submissions
LEFT JOIN
    comments
ON
    submissions.id=comments.submission_id
WHERE
    submissions.user_id = ?
GROUP BY comment
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this? The reason I originally didn't combine the first two queries, is because count is always going to return one row for the whole query.

Comment: The join query looks fine. Have you tried running it? Note that the `?` in it means a placeholder parameter, for use in prepared statements. Your original version did direct query-building.

Comment: I understand about the placeholder. I'm using PDO with prepared statements. As for that query, I get the following error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'comments.submission_id FROM submissions LEFT JOIN ' at line 9`

Comment: Ah easy enough you're missing a comma after the `COUNT(...) as ...` line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (I just added a comma after `comment` based upon your comment with the error):

```
    SELECT
        submissions.user_id,
        submissions.id,
        submissions.quote,
        submissions.filename,
        submissions.date_added,
        submissions.views,
        COUNT(comments.id) as `comment`,
        comments.submission_id

    FROM
        submissions
    LEFT JOIN
        comments
    ON
        submissions.id=comments.submission_id
    WHERE
        submissions.user_id = ?
    GROUP BY submissions.user_id,
        submissions.id,
        submissions.quote,
        submissions.filename,
        submissions.date_added,
        submissions.views,
        comments.submission_id
```

Comment: Wow that was amazingly quick. Thank you!